# What are the latest Odds?

Tags: optimization, sql, django, postgresql

The main problem the following query is solving, is the following:

Each `Offer` has multiple `Odds` (`Odds` has foreignkey to `Offer`). For each offer I want the latest `Odds` (`ORDER BY time`).

I'm pretty sure this is too heavy, so any input would be great.

```
SELECT "odds_odds"."id", "odds_odds"."offer_id", "odds_odds"."time", "odds_odds"."o1", "odds_odds"."o2", "odds_odds"."o3", "odds_odds"."o4", MAX(T3."time") AS "max_time" 
FROM "odds_odds" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "odds_offer" ON ( "odds_odds"."offer_id" = "odds_offer"."id" )
LEFT OUTER JOIN "odds_odds" T3 ON ( "odds_offer"."id" = T3."offer_id" ) 
GROUP BY "odds_odds"."id", "odds_odds"."offer_id", "odds_odds"."time", "odds_odds"."o1", "odds_odds"."o2", "odds_odds"."o3", "odds_odds"."o4" 
HAVING "odds_odds"."time" =  MAX(T3."time")
```

This is constructed in Django using the following syntax:

```
Odds.objects.annotate(
    max_time=Max('offer__odds__time')
).filter(
    time=F('max_time')
)
```

This is my schema:

```
odds_offer
id (int), .....

odds_odds
id (int), time (datetime), offer_id(int), .....
```

Now what I want to retrieve *The `Odds` row with the latest `time` for each `Offer`*. There is a unique constraint on `(time, offer_id)`. One `Offer` can have multiple odds (historic odds).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be **radically simpler and faster** with the Postgres specific [`DISTINCT ON`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (offer_id)
       offer_id, id, time, o1, o2, o3, o4, time  -- or just * to include all columns
FROM   odds_odds
ORDER  BY offer_id, time DESC;
```

You don't need to touch the table `odds_offer` at all. Note that you only get odds of offers that have at least one related row in `odds_odds` this way (obviously). *If* you'd want to include offers without any related odds somehow, you'd need to do a bit more, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Depending on data distribution there may be even faster variants.
Detailed explanation and links in this related answer on SO:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

Answer (score 4):

## **Formatting**

I think your query could really use some white space to make it easier to read. I realize there is no official standard for SQL, but here is my preferred style:

```
SELECT 
    "odds_odds"."id", 
    "odds_odds"."offer_id", 
    "odds_odds"."time", 
    "odds_odds"."o1", 
    "odds_odds"."o2", 
    "odds_odds"."o3", 
    "odds_odds"."o4", 
    MAX(T3."time") AS "max_time" 
FROM "odds_odds" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "odds_offer" 
        ON ( "odds_odds"."offer_id" = "odds_offer"."id" )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "odds_odds" T3 
        ON ( "odds_offer"."id" = T3."offer_id" ) 
GROUP BY 
    "odds_odds"."id", 
    "odds_odds"."offer_id", 
    "odds_odds"."time", 
    "odds_odds"."o1", 
    "odds_odds"."o2", 
    "odds_odds"."o3", 
    "odds_odds"."o4" 
HAVING "odds_odds"."time" =  MAX(T3."time");
```

## **Table aliases**

A table named `"odds_odds"` seems *odd* to me, but you could save some typing by aliasing as `odds` at least. Also not sure why you are using quotation marks everywhere, but maybe it's a requirement for your system. I have a Postgres database and never needed those, so it just feels like noise.

## **Simplifying**

You said:

> For each offer I want the latest `Odds` (`ORDER BY time`).

What I see your code doing is what seems like unnecessary computation to find `MAX()`, where you likely could entirely remove your aggregation and write something along those lines:

```
SELECT 
    "odds_odds"."id", 
    "odds_odds"."offer_id", 
    "odds_odds"."time", 
    "odds_odds"."o1", 
    "odds_odds"."o2", 
    "odds_odds"."o3", 
    "odds_odds"."o4", 
    T3."time" AS "max_time" 
FROM "odds_odds" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "odds_offer" 
        ON ( "odds_odds"."offer_id" = "odds_offer"."id" )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "odds_odds" T3 
        ON ( "odds_offer"."id" = T3."offer_id" ) 
ORDER BY "odds_odds"."time" DESC
LIMIT 1; -- or however many you need
```

Comment: Interesting solution. I wish I could see the differences in query plans.

Comment: Me too. I can't imagine that sorting the result set (instead of computing the source set) wouldn't be faster, but I will try to test it out.

Comment: Thanks. However, this gives me only the `Odds` with the highest "time" field - which is not what I want. For each `Offer` in the database - I want the `Odds` from that `Offer` with the "highest" `time` - that's why I'm using the `Max`.

Comment: @Martol1ni It would have helped if you mentioned that in your question. You said "latest time" which to most means the most recent time. If your `"time"` column a cumulative time rather than an actual time/date?

Comment: I'm sorry - that's what the current query is doing, I've not edited my question.

Comment: If you feel my answer is inapropriate you are welcome to downvote or even flag for moderator attention. As it stands, I'm really confused about what you are trying to do.

Comment: "For each offer I want the latest `Odds`" — sounds like the result should consist of more than one row. That would be a window query, I think.

Comment: Could be, don't know much about those. Maybe you could venture an answer @200_success ?